# Parse CloudCode won't show my app

Tags: android, powershell, parse-cloud-code

I'm beginning to use CloudCode but I can't find my application after authentication.
Once I enter my email account and pass I get the following:
**Email: 
Pass: 
1: results
Select an App:**

From this step nothing works (Ex. parse deploy) and I get the error msg "Unknown application _default"

I'm using the latest parse-windows.2.0.11.exe, PowerShell on Win8.1

Should CloudCode be activate on the project in order to use it? if so, how is this done?

===UPDATE===
It turns out the global.json was created wrong (bug?)

```
{
"applications": {
    "results": {
        "applicationId": {
            "appName": "AppName1", 
            "applicationId": "zzz", 
            "masterKey": "zzz"
        }, 
        "masterKey": {
            "appName": "AppName2", 
            "applicationId": "xxx", 
            "masterKey": "xxx"
        }
    }
}
```

}

I've manually fixed it using this thread [link](https://www.parse.com/questions/parse-add-alias-problem)
Hope this will help others..

=== END UPDATE===

Please advise.

Thanks,
Liran

Answer (score 1):

My experience is with Android over Linux, but from what I see the base is the same - in Linux you create a folder for your CloudCode that you reference for deployments, so when you deploy you do that from inside that folder, read carefully through [This Parse Tutorial](https://www.parse.com/docs/dotnet/guide#cloud-code) - seems pretty similar.

Comment: Thanks! your comment lead me to find about the file structure which finally fixed the issue.

Comment: no prob, if it helped please consider upvoting (if you can) :)